# Arrange elements without CSS in Webix

Tags: user-interface, alignment, webix

I'm very new to Webix and wonder if there's a way to arrange elements on a page avoiding css?
For example, here's the toolbar with three buttons. How can I set something like `align:right` to them?

```
webix.ui({  
  rows: [
    { 
      view:"toolbar", elements:[      
        { view:"button", value:"B1", width: 70},        
        { view:"button", value:"B2", width: 70 },        
        { view:"button", value:"B3", width: 70 },      
      ]    
    },       
    { template:""}   
  ]
});
```

Code snippet:
http://webix.com/snippet/deb1c886

Answer (score 1):

Almost all positioning of the elements in Webix based on the dividing the page into rows and columns. And if you need to align the button (or buttons), you can just put empty view `{},` anywhere. 
For example

```
view:"toolbar", elements:[  
    {},
    { view:"button", value:"B1", width: 70},        
    { view:"button", value:"B2", width: 70 },        
    { view:"button", value:"B3", width: 70 },      
  ]
```

will arrange all your buttons to the right.